# Ubuntu 13.10 slow boot Nvidia Graphics card

Tags: boot, nvidia, 13.10, bootchart

My boot time takes almost 2 mins and I have tested it with **bootcharts**. I do not know what is wrong and it started appearing only when I installed the drivers for my Nvidia Graphics card.

**EDIT:** I'm using the nvidia 331.20 driver from Xorg-edgers. I'm running a NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] graphics card

How do I start to make my computer boot faster and make it more stable? It hangs often but is fine after suspending or sleeping it.

Comment: I would first need to know what Nvidia driver version you are using. Is it official, PPA or from the Ubuntu repositories. I would also invite you to read http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433 . It might help you a bit with this.

Comment: Hi Luis, it is nvidia 331.20 from Xorg-edgers. I'm running a NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] graphics card btw. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Albino, I recommend testing the nvidia-304 package instead of the nvidia-331. This is because the 304 is more oriented towards your 310M video card. Remove the 331 and test the 304. See if that works.

Comment: Hi Luis I tried uninstalling the 331 and using 304. It boots up to give a photosizure inducing flashing black screen w a cursor. It didnt make it to the login page. I purged all drivers and it now works on nvidia-common. its alright but hangs when I need external monitors. Is it usual for nvidia drivers to be problematic or can it be due to my lightdm or other conflicts?

Comment: There might more that meets the eye. What I would do is: 1. Uninstall every nvidia proprietary driver and boot with the open source one (Remember to delete the hidden files and folders in your home folder related to nvidia). After checking that everything is working correctly then proceed installing the nvidia version you want. I would recommend the 304 again or 310 before jumping to the latest one because of your nvidia card. Rinse and repeat until you find the one that works correctly with your card. Let me know how it goes. If there is any problem please output the lines in dmesg related.

Comment: I spent another 4 hours on it and I sort of figured that it was my xorg.conf giving me trouble. After installation I ran nvidia-xconfig and gave the flashing screen. I purged and added bumblebee w the nvidia driver and the same flashing screen appeared. It might be all due to the xorg.conf but im unsure if any drivers are used as I dont see any drivers used under the VGA section when I run lspci -k. Thanks for your help Luis =)

Comment: I read the boot chart and I was wondering why you still have the 3.8 Kernel. In my case I have activated all repositories (including proposed) and I have the 3.11 kernel. This might influence your video card. Also what I was going to mention is if you upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 or did a clean install. And can you please put all info about your hardware here. This can help us in figuring out the problem. I also made a book for stuff like this here: http://luisviloria.com/?p=65

Comment: Hi Luis, heres the link for the hardware specs [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0b1ezac0q7u9qxr/hardware), my recent bootchart after the kernel upgrade to 3.11 [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewvtm5r5mxmm139/ubuntu-saucy-20131201-9.png) and the dmesg output[logfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/485lt0b1eibm5e6/logfile). It was an upgrade from 13.04 and I am afraid to do a clean install as I am afraid of losing my database project installed. I'm not sure but would it affect my files if I do a clean install and can I retain my setup?

Comment: I can help you further with the clean install including the database but it would require either using the chat here or contacting me via email. In general, you will not loose anything so do not worry about it, but there are a couple of steps you need to do to assure that everything gets backed up correctly and then restored correctly.